# Django unable to read the model of other app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

here is the directory format. I have 4 apps.

```
-project (dir)
    -accounts
    -subscription
    -PROJECTAPP
    -basiclinks
```

I have already read out all the articles and failed so asked.

The model class is in subscription and I want to import that into accounts

```
from project.subscription.models import Package
```

*Its throwing error that there is no module named project.subscription.

Comment: Did you add your apps into settings file INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: yes added in installed apps

Comment: other apps are under of project app, am i right?

Comment: yess all the apps inside the project folder

Comment: Could you try import withouth project directory. Like that `from subscription.models import Package`